# f:ajax event called twice

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

My f:ajax event is being triggered twice. Below is the code.

```
<h:panelGroup id="test" layout="block">
<div class="checkbox #{MB.addNewForm eq 'true' ? 'checked' : ''}">
    <label> 
        <input name="checkboxOption0" type="checkbox" />
        <strong>Add new account</strong>
    </label>
</div>
<f:ajax event="click" render="@all" execute="@form" listener="#{MB.toggleAddNewAccountForm}" />
```

How can I stop it from being triggered twice.

Comment: Please provide all code snippet in between <form> tags.

Comment: its huge. what do you want to know. Please tell me.

Comment: Just post problematic code in MCVE format and make sure you supply minimally required information in order for us to be able to reproduce it on a scratchpad project. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info